# split strings in a cell into different row, pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to split this cell in different rows in pandas dataframe, basically splitting strings but ignoring the comma inside quotes.

```
'one two three', 'don't split, this'
```

output would be like:

```
'one two three'
'don't split, this'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the type of the complete string? Is it a list, or a string itself? Please give a proper (complete) example, not just a few strings, but an actual dataframe showing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
df['col'].str.split(r"(?<=')[,(\s|)](?=')")
```

Or if there always be a space after the comma, do:

```
s.str.split(r"(?<='), (?=')")
```